# Mongodb upgrade collections now missing

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I've very very new to Mongodb so apologies if this is a stupid question.

I installed Mongodb and played around with creating some collections etc. I then wanted to try some aggregate functions but discovered I needed to upgrade.

I upgraded with homebrew, the upgrade seemed to work fine, but when I fire up mongod and mongo I can't see my collections anymore. I've tried to fire up mongod with the --upgrade option but still no joy. When I call 'show dbs' it shows that my test db is empty.

Curious as to what's happened here and how I can recover the collections.

Comment: The files may have been deleted by the upgrade, or the path it's using for storing the data may have changed. Look in the locations suggested [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--dbpath). If you did `use dbs` for example, look for a file called `dbs.ns` on your Mac. It should have some other files with it in a single directory (like `dbs.0`, `dbs.1`). Match the timestamps to be sure it's not what you're currently using. You need to start `mongod` with  `--dbpath` and point to that location.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have a feeling I probably deleted them in the upgrade, so lesson learned there, always backup the data folder before and upgrade!

Comment: Did you do the original Mongodb installation with homebrew, too? The mongodb upgrade should have preserved your databases, both their configuration and data. If a `brew upgrade mongodb` was destructive, that's probably a bug in the formula and should be reported over at the Homebrew issue tracker: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, pretty certain I did both with homebrew, but I can't be 100% sure as being a first time user I was faffing about with it kind of blindly. I'll try it again and if I get the same problem i'll report it.

Comment: Go to the db folder on the filesystem and try to find the datbaase files.  There should be one that ends with .ns and the rest will end in .1, .2, .3, etc.  Are the files there?  What are the file sizes?

Answer (score 0):

**losing databases after upgrading mongodb to newer version:**
Maybe it's too late to answer this 9 years old question. but i faced exactly the same issue last night. i lost all of my databases with more than one month working on them.i had multiple backups but never backed up in structured directory. so maybe beginners like me someday need to find a way to get rid of the issue.
soloution:
after upgrading mongodb to newer version , mongodb windows service executable path switchs to path of newer version executable path.the newer version only looks to new databases path. so if you want to have access to older version mongodb databases on localhost , you simply should change the path of mongodb windows service executable path to older version directory in "c:\program files\mongodb\server<version directory>\bin\mongod.exe"

after that, start service again , run mongodb and connect to local host . perform show dbs command . disappeared database should be there!